# How do I get The Ghost achievement?

Tags: achievements, jetpack-joyride

I am struggling to achieve the award "The Ghost" in Jetpack Joyride. The achievement description states, "You need to get in without breaking the laboratory wall". What trick do I use to do this?

Comment: Is this question about jetpack joyride or dragonvale world? Based on the body, I'm going to assume jetpack joyride. If that's wrong, feel free to retag. Please leave the achievements tag, though.

Answer (score 3):

Unless it's been renamed since I was playing, I believe this achievement is actually called "Another Way In."  I earned it by using the "Free Ride" gadget (you begin the game with a random vehicle) and I played that way until the random vehicle I began with was the teleporter.  The wall doesn't break, you just teleport into the level.